# Advantage of using nonideal filter in purely digital application

Tags: matlab, digital-filters

Say I'd like to bandpass filter a signal with corner frequencies 1 kHz and 2 kHz (i.e., passes signals between 1 kHz and 2 kHz and suppresses other frequencies) using software like MATLAB. Intuition tells me there's two ways to do this:

1. Use filter design tools to create, say, a 10th order Butterworth filter. Use the *filter* command with the filter coefficients and input signal. This works, but the filter is nonideal (specifically, there will be some passband ripple, and the frequency cutoffs won't be immediate -- a signal at say, 2.1 kHz, will still be partially passed).
2. Perform an FFT on the input signal. Set any FFT element corresponding to a frequency outside the 1 kHz-2 kHz range to zero. Inverse FFT the input signal. This will essentially be an ideal filter -- anything between 1kHz-2 kHz is passed with unity gain (no passband ripple), and anything outside 1  kHz-2 KHz is exactly zero (immediate cutoff).

Intuition tells me that #2 is better, because it's an ideal filter. I've learned that an ideal filter can't be built using analog components, but if a certain application is purely digital, why not use the ideal filter?

That being said, I've seen lots of code that uses tools like a nonideal 10th order Butterworth filter -- so what am I overlooking? What's the advantage of using a nonideal filter?

Comment: There are many similar questions on the website; for example: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16359/simple-fft-filtering-vs-e-g-butterworth-filtering or https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins/6224.

Comment: there is no passband ripple with a Butterworth prototype.  no stopband ripple either.  Butterworth is smooth as a baby-bottom.  like $\omega$.  and remember (regarding your #2), that FFT and iFFT do **circular convolution** and that the frequency response $H[k]$ has to correspond to a finite-length impulse response, h[n], an "FIR".  i don't think your $H[k]$ does really.

Comment: The advantage of non-ideal filters is that they can be implemented. Ideal ones can't. [This answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins) will help you understand why your #2 does not work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption #2 is false.  Zeroing bins does not produce an ideal filter with unity gain in the passband.  Far from it if you look closely (between FFT bins).