# ITU-R 2k filter implementation

Tags: filters

How to generate the coefficients of an itu-r 2k filter when all I know is my 0 dB point is at 2 kHz and my maximum of 6 dB is at 7 kHz

Comment: I assume you're talking about a digital implementation. What kind of filter do you want to use?

Comment: i have an array to which I do an FFT on and then a low pass, and in the end I need to apply an itu-r 2k filter which acts the same as an itu-r 468 filter but it is 6dB shifted. I know I need to multiply the array I have with an array of the same size which contains the coefficients of this filter but I do not know how to generate them when all I know is my 0 dB point and my maximum

Comment: You don't actually implement very good filters by simply multiplying FFT bins (see [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins)) and its answers. Or do you use overlap-add or overlap-save?

Comment: I have done the FFT already and that is all fine, I then apply a low pass filter on my array of data and the last step is applying the itu-r arm 2 kHz filter which I do not know how to do.

Comment: I understood that, but my point was that you can't implement the itu-r arm filter by just multiplying your FFT array by some weights. The same is true for the low pass filter.