# 3dB and 6dB Per Octave Rolloff Digital Filters / Generating Pink and Brown Noise

Tags: filters, filter-design, noise, c, octave

So I would like to have a design method for filters with 3dB and 6dB per octave roll off -- for generating pink and brown noise respectively.

I know the following 'pinking' filters exist:
[Filter to add 3dB per octave?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27520/filter-to-add-3db-per-octave)

But the poster says he doesn't remember the value for A, nor does he give any idea of how he did it in the first place.

*So my main question is:*

**How do we pick the poles and zeros of such a filter?**

Comment: oh, the dude's talking about me.  just groked that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I have figured out the answer, thanks to a little prodding by RBJ.

**Creating -6dB/octave Filters and Brown Noise:**

1. Generate a White Noise Sequence.
2. Design a 1st Order Butterworth Filter
3. Apply 1st Order Buttworth to the White Noise Sequence
   [Use the Bilinear Transform to convert the analog coefficients to digital, and apply the digital filter to the white noise sequence].

**Creating -3dB/octave Filters and Pink Noise:**

1. Generate a White Noise Sequence
2. Generate arbitrary interleaved poles and zeros on the positive real line within the unit circle. Such that $|p_{i}| > |z_{i}|$ and $|z_{i}| > |p_{i+1}|$. Set the first pole close to the unit circle.
3. Convert these roots to coefficients, and use these coefficients as the coefficients of a digital filter.
4. Apply said digital filter to the White Noise Sequence.

What I am still not sure of is why we need to interleave the poles and zeros, but that isn't exactly what the question asked. Can anybody elaborate?

Comment: Browning filter: should be 1-pole LPF with the zero at $z=-1$.  all such 1-pole filters are, strictly speaking, a Butterworth, but they are also a 1-pole Tchebyshev, etc.  the "Butterworth" distinction is not relevant until you get to 2nd-order filters and above, so Q or resonance becomes an issue.

Answer (score 3):

-6 dB / octave is trivial.

a common reference for a pinking filter is http://www.firstpr.com.au/dsp/pink-noise/

Comment: Wow you are super helpful. What would we ever do without you?

Comment: Btw, that was sarcasm. You failed to answer the question, completely, [and also linked something which I also linked in my original post] so you don't deserve that +1 there.

Comment: okay, Dude, it's a slope of about -3 dB/octave.  you can make whatever value for $A$ for however loud you wanna make it.  it isn't equally loud at all frequencies.  the 3 poles and 3 zeros in the link above with an $A=0.923$ will have that -3 dB/octave ramp cross 0 dB at about 0.322 Nyquist or $\omega \approx 1$.  decide where you want whatever gain you want at whatever frequency and set $A$ with respect to that.

Comment: you would have the same kinda issue with a simple 1-pole LPF to do brown or red noise.  where do you want the -6 dB/octave ramp to cross the 0 dB level?

Comment: Now we may be getting somewhere. So, if I want to do brown noise, I need to design a simple 1 pole LPF. So I let my cutoff frequency be wc = 2 * pi * fc, with fc in hertz. I take wc, prewarp it, and design a 1st order Butterworth filter. Using the bilinear transform, I convert it into a discrete filter, and there I am. This filter should cross the 3dB level at wc.

But, how do I do -3dB/octave? Why did you pick 3 poles and 3 zeros? What filter design did you use?

Comment: So from your post on the pinking filter, I need to alternate real poles and zeros. So from the edge of the unit circle back down to the origin, the pole-zero diagram should look like [pole1, zero1, pole2, zero2, pole3, zero3, ...etc]. Where |pole_i| > |zero_i| and |zero_i| > |pole_{i+1}|. From here, since they are in the Z-domain already, I can design the digital coefficients directly. 

Why is this structure needed? What if I want to use complex poles and zeros -- do I need to still follow a radial line down to the origin? 

How do you pick A? Trial and Error?

Comment: the spacing of the poles and zeros were roughly equal in log-frequency.  they had to be bumped around by trial and error.  complex poles and zeros were not particularly useful since the slope i wanted was half the slope of a single real pole.  trial, measure, and adjust on A.  all this is pretty easy with MATLAB.  i did this originally back in the 80s with a C compiler running on an old B&W Mac.

Comment: i guess another criterion for choosing A is so the pinking filter (or browning filter) has the same aggregate power coming out (over a given frequency range) as power going in.  then some frequencies will be boosted and others will be cut.  and you'll know the power going in if you have a good random number generator.  still sorta a trial, measure, and adjust thing with MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

here's what to do for -3 dB/octave (what i remember from 1985):

first take your 1/sqrt(f) magnitude function and **inverse**-warp that frequency response to what it will look like in the analog s-domain.  instead of only a -3 dB/oct ramp (which is what you **after** BLT frequency warping) you have a -3 dB/oct ramp that starts to level out a little in the s-domain.

Then apply straight line ramps at -6 dB/oct and 0 dB/oct (like with "Bode plots, remember them from electronics class?) to approximate your pre-warped ramp.  convert those alternating poles and zeros to digital using the BLT.  then your pre-warped ramp will come out like a straight ramp after BLT frequency warping.  then adjust the pole or zero that is on the **edges** to minimize the maximum error in the log-log plot in the digital domain.