# What's a "Fourier filter"?

Tags: fourier-transform

E.g. the constant Q-transform is built by adding so called "Fourier filters".

What's a "Fourier filter"?

Comment: Here (http://doc.ml.tu-berlin.de/bbci/material/publications/Bla_constQ.pdf) the Fourier filter is claimed to be $\sum_{n<N}x[n]e^{-2\pi i nz /N}$.

Comment: I've updated my answer, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People (usually from fields outside signal processing) sometimes use the term [Fourier filter](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/FourierFilter.html) for a filtering operation in the FFT domain, which simply works by multiplying the FFT bins of a signal with a given filter function (often just ones and zeros, corresponding to pass bands and stop bands, respectively). Why this is generally not such a good idea is explained [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins).

Also in Computer Vision, the term [Fourier filter](https://books.google.nl/books?id=ZCu8BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA422&ots=sPE4rKyiWs&dq=%22fourier%20filter%22%20formula&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false) is used as explained above.

In the [document](http://doc.ml.tu-berlin.de/bbci/material/publications/Bla_constQ.pdf) you linked to in a comment, the term is used to describe the computation of the Discrete-Time Fourier Transform (DTFT) at a given frequency from a finite length portion of a signal. This computation can be interpreted as a filtering operation, because it is a sum of products. The corresponding filter is a band pass filter with center frequency equal to the given DTFT frequency. More more information on the filter interpretation of the D(T)FT have a look at [this page](http://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/DFT_Filter_Bank.html).

Comment: See my comment on the question.

Comment: Should those filter functions need to be transformed (presumably into Frequency domain) as well before multiplying with the FFT bins of a signal?

I am beginner in applying theory into practice. Please bare with trivial things.

Comment: @jomegaA: Normally, they are very simple, so they can be "designed" directly in the frequency domain (e.g., they might only consist of 1's and 0's, as mentioned in my answer).

Comment: @MattL. Ok. If I choose Hann window for example, I must transform the window into frequency domain before multiplying with FFT bins of signal, presume I work in Frequency domain.

In time-domain I convolve the signal with window to get the output.

Comment: @jomegaA: A window is not meant to be a filter; usually you multiply your time domain signal with a window, but you don't filter it with a window.

Answer (score 0):

Each bin of a DFT or FFT result can be considered to be the result of a filter operation.   Each filter's frequency response is either Sinc shaped, or if a non-rectangular window is applied before the FFT, the response will be shaped like the transform of that window, with a passband width roughly proportional to from Fs/N to twice that.

Computing a single unwindowed DFT bin is nearly identical to a Goertzel filter.  So that's yet another potential synonym for the same thing.