# How to implement a time-varying filter?

Tags: filters, frequency-spectrum, filter-design, lowpass-filter, frequency-response

I'm working on a 10-second sound, sampled at 44.1 khz.

I want to do filtering, and have a **desired EQ (equalization) curve that varies over time**, as suggested here (here $f0=250\ Hz$)

[image]

**How to implement a time-varying filter**?

1. How to go from this [bad idea of zeroing FFT bins](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins)

   ```
   [0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0, ... 0]
      |           |             |             |
      |          freq bins for f0, 2*f0, 3*f0  are kept
      |
    most freq bins are zeroed
   ```

   to a good filtering?
2. Then, how to make this vary over time? Should I use overlap-add, etc.? Then if so, can't I do it inside a STFT framework?
3. Would you have a pseudo code or Python demo?

*PS: I've read http://recherche.ircam.fr/anasyn/roebel/amt_audiosignale/VL3.pdf, but I can't go from here to a working algorithm.*

Comment: I think any adaptive filter strategy, time varying filter is a very ambicious term, is the proper starting point. Some parameter estimation technique, according to your working skills and motivations, this can be solved in a lot of ways...

Comment: Also, do you have a clear idea of what do you want or need to equalize? An equalizer is a frequency flattener, not a noise reducer.

Comment: @hypfco I finally did it by STFT zeroing bins. I have to say the result is really pretty clean, STFT-zeroing-bins doesnt' have the drawbacks of FFT-zeroing-bins because windowing is already applied during the STFT process.

Comment: LOL congratulations then!!!

Comment: More about this question [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36294/zero-stft-bins-and-not-fft-bins?rq=1).