# How do I apply a binary mask and STFT to produce an audio file?

Tags: python, spectrogram, stft, linear-algebra

So here's the idea: you can generate a spectrogram from an audio file using shorttime Fourier transform (stft). Then some people have generated something called a "binary mask" to generate different audio (ie. with background noise removed etc.) from the inverse stft.

Here's what I understand:

stft is a simple equation that is applied to the audio file, which generates the information that can easily be displayed a spectrogram. By taking the inverse of the stft matrix, and multiplying it by a matrix of the same size (the binary matrix) you can create a new matrix with information to generate an audio file with the masked sound.

**Once I do the matrix multiplication, how is the new audio file created?**

It's not much but here's what I've got in terms of code:

```
from librosa import load
from librosa.core import stft, istft
y, sample_rate = load('1.wav')
spectrum = stft(y)
back_y = istft(spectrum)
```

Thank you, and here are some slides that got me this far. I'd appreciate it if you could give me an example/demo in python

Comment: Hi Blake! It seems you are a little bit naive about STFT, spectogram and audio files... I suggest you understand each block better before combining them to remove background noise as ascribed.

Comment: binary masks in the freuency domain are not a good idea https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins

Comment: Thanks! you'd be right that I'm new to this! Here, I was reading this, and it seems that they used applied a mask to the stft, then used the inverse to get back the audio with the voices separated. Am I talking about something else?https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04662.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the short-time Fourier transform (STFT) in this case is to compute a representation of the input signal where we see how the frequency content of the signal evolves over time. If you aren't familiar with the STFT, I would suggest you read up on it a bit first. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) on the subject should get you started.

To your question. The [STFT function](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stft.html) in your code gives you a complex-valued matrix in the output. When you move up or down a column in the matrix you are moving in the frequency direction. When you move along a row in the matrix you are moving along the time direction. The magnitude of a single complex-valued element in the matrix gives you an estimate of the energy in a certain frequency band at a certain time position in the input signal.

I recommend you try to understand the parameters that are given to you in the function call. You should try to understand how the *window size*, *hop size*, *number of FFT bins*, and the *windowing function* used affect the output of the function.

If we denote your complex valued STFT with $$X = \textrm{STFT\{x(n)\}},$$ and the binary mask with $M$, the output signal in the time-frequency domain is given by:

$$Y = X \odot M,$$
where $\odot$ refers to element-wise multiplication. Then you want to convert your modified time-frequency representation $Y$ back into to a time signal. This is done by doing the inverse STFT:

$$y(n) = \textrm{ISTFT}\{Y\}.$$

This should get you going, but time-frequency processing is a complex topic and I highly recommend trying to find resources to help you really understand what is going on when you are doing things such as [applying a binary mask in the STFT-domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins).

Comment: wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. I feel like it really fills a lot of the holes in terms of my understanding!