# Is ideal band pass filter (brick wall filter) linear phase?

Tags: filters, bandpass, linear-phase

I'm very new in digital signal processing.
I have multiple sensors and the way I filters the signals in post processing is:

1. take FFT of the signals.
2. put zero on out range of interesting frequency (like brick wall filter).
3. take IFFT of the spectrum.

I repeat this for each sensor, and compare the phase relation between them in time traces. Thus, the phase must not shift during the filtering process. I wonder the above method distorts the phase or not. Is the ideal band pass filter linear phase?

Comment: this is not a process running continuously, is it?  __ or are you doing these three steps once to a piece of data?

Comment: look at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins   ,

Comment: I did this in post processing, it's not a real time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are refering to LTI (linear time-invariant) systems to implement the filter.

The impulse response $h[n]$ of the ideal brickwall bandpass filter :
$$H(\omega) = \begin{cases} 1 ~~~,~~~ |\omega-\omega_c|<W \\ 0 ~~~,~~~\text{o.w.}\\ \end{cases}$$ 
is 
$$
h[n] = 2 \cos(\omega_c n) \frac{ \sin(W n) }{ \pi n }
$$

which is real and even symetric about origin; i.e., $h[n] = h[-n]$,  hence it's a zero-phase (in the passband), but noncausal filter.

When this impulse response is truncated and shifted right enough to make it causal: $h_c[n] = h[n-d]$ then the resulting bandpass filter will be linear phase in the passband: 
$$ H_c(\omega)= e^{-j\omega d} H(\omega)$$ with a linear phase term of $$\phi(\omega) = -\omega d$$

The phase is not defined for those frequencies where the frequency response is zero.

Note that the truncated filter is no more the **ideal** filter. Also note that you cannot shift the ideal filter to make it causal (requires infinite shift). And finally note that the zero-phase ideal filter is also a linear phase filter.