# How enhance amplitude of audio signal without distortion?

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, python, normalization, enhancement

After FFT I've set to zero some frequencies and I'd like to enhance the amplitude in order to recover the leak. 
I'd like to do a normalization in order to avoid distortion.
I've done in this way but the new signal is between 0 and 1 and so the result is incorrect:

```
maximum_data = np.max(fftdata)
minimum_data = np.min(fftdata)
maximum_abs = np.max(fftabs)
minimum_abs = np.min(fftabs)
normalization_factor = ((2**16)/2)-1
for i in range(len(fftdata)):
    fftdata[i] = ((fftdata[i] - minimum_data)/(maximum_data - minimum_data))*normalization_factor
    fftabs[i] = ((fftabs[i] - minimum_abs)/(maximum_abs - minimum_abs))*normalization_factor
```

How can I resolve the problem? What is the correct formula?
Thanks.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend not simply zeroing out bins in the fft. See [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins) very helpful question.

Comment: To answer the question in your title: multiply with a constant number > 1.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I need a normalization of my signal in the range [-32768; 32767] in order to avoid distortion caused by any constant number.

Comment: Normalization *is* multiplication with a constant number. I'm really not sure what you're asking for here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I explain better with an example: originally my signal stays in [-32768; 32768] (it is codified with pcm 16 bit); after zeroing FFT bins, the signal stays in [-10000; 7500]. Now, I'd like that the signals stays in [-32768; 32767] again.

Comment: Slightly repeating myself: So, multiply it with a constant. In this case, the constant would be $\min(\frac{-32768}{-10000}, \frac{32767}{7500})$.

Comment: and to also repeat myself: as said in my first comment, zeroing out FFT bins is very rarely appropriate processing.