# Removing striped noise from an image

Tags: image-processing, filters, fourier-transform, image-restoration

I was just wondering if anyone could explain to me the approach one would take to removing striped noise from the fourier domain of an image. I was reading an article about MRI image from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3JZG.png) just giving a general outline of the location of spatial frequencies, and it had a slide (displayed below) which got me thinking in how I would attempt to remove the striped noise.

My original thought was to just block the given frequency with a mask but if I set the mask to 0 then I would have to be pretty accurate with the mask so I dont block out any other components that may be necessary for the image.

My second idea which I am not sure on is as each point the frequency domain is represented by phase and a modulus could I somehow use that to remove the striped noise?

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3JZG.png) http://mriquestions.com/locations-in-k-space.html

Answer (score 1):

I have solved a similar problem using an [*Ideal low-pass filter*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#:%7E:text=An%20ideal%20low%2Dpass%20filter%20completely%20eliminates%20all%20frequencies%20above,exist%20in%20an%20ideal%20filter.). The idea of the process is rather simple: eliminate all frequencies above a certain threshold, while passing the ones below it. If you plot the *Power spectrum* of the noisy image, you will spot two dots which correspond to the stripes (one in the top-left quadrant, one in the bottom-right quadrant). Therefore, you should aim to set the *threshold* as close to those dots as possible but strictly below them. Here is a plot that visualizes the process of applying an *Ideal low-pass filter* to a noisy version of the *trui.png*.

[image]

The reason why the filtered image is slightly blurrier than the original one is because the low frequencies are around the centre of the *Power spectrum* and we cut off all frequencies higher than the threshold.

**Note:** I have modified the stripes in a way such that they result in convenient dots in the frequency domain. This makes it easier to filter them out using the *Ideal low-pass filter*. Keep in mind that in reality, the dots might be way closer to the centre of the *Power spectrum*, thus hindering the *Ideal low-pass filter*'s performance.

Hopefully, I was able to point you in the right direction. You can refer to *C. Gonzalez, E. Woods* if you are interested in the theory behind the filter. Moreover, you might be able to find a better solution to this problem in the book.

Comment: So you just [zeroed DFT bins](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/6220/50076)? There should be a disclaimer on this generally worst implementation of "ideal low-pass". I figure it works here per the would-be smooth transition band being low energy.

Comment: Thanks for linking this thread. The approach definitely has its flaws and I did elaborate a bit on them.