# How many things can they be done with a spectrogram?

Tags: filters, frequency-spectrum, spectrogram

I found some things that can be done with a spectrogram.

- filter frequencies by setting the bins to zero
- observe what frequencies make up the signal.
- observe the energy or
  amplitude of each frequency, the whitest pixel has more volume and the black pixels have little amplitude.
- observe harmonics

It does not occur to me that other things can be done.

Comment: "how many things can be done?" 12912.3 things. This isn't really a precisely answerable question, is it? Can you maybe rephrase your question to be meaningfully answerable, and maybe include why you're wondering?

Comment: by the way, your 1. point is usually not a good idea (see [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins?r=SearchResults&s=2|35.2826)), and question 2 & 4 are just 3 (and the colors are just an arbitrary decision made by your UI designer)

Answer (score 0):

A spectrogram is a reversible (and generally redundant and complex) transformation that is used to separate components, unmix latent signals, some of which being related to frequency analysis (Nota: sometimes, this name is used for the (squared) magnitude of the above. I do use it as a short-hand for the breeds of short-term Fourier transforms).

We can note that the classical Fourier transform is a (simplistic)   form of spectrograms. **So anything you can do with Fourier, you can expect to do it (possibly better) with spectrograms**.

For instance, spectrograms can be used  to sparsify representations (reduce the proportion of useful components) or to emphasize features from non-stationary signals. So any signal processing technique, that could use the former [sparsifying preprocessing](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.3654) (could be an FFT alone)), fits the picture: time-frequency cancellation, detection, noise estimation and removal, segmentation, deconvolution, adaptive filtering, source separation, learning, etc.

For instance, even mp3 or JPEG compression are based on a sort of (non-redundant) spectrograms.