# How to properly filter offline data by zeroing the unwanted frequencies after FFT?

Tags: fft, filters, lowpass-filter, ifft

I am new to the field of DSP. I have a measured signal, and I wanted to apply a low pass filter on the data. I just simply applied FFT, wrote zeroes at the unwanted frequencies then applied inverse FFT. But I had got complex numbers instead of real values. What is the proper way of doing this kind of filtering? How to get back the filtered time signal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it a bad idea to filter by zeroing out FFT bins?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins)

Comment: Did you get complex numbers with significant imaginary parts, or with imaginary parts that were teeny with respect to the real data (i.e., numbers like 0.5 - 1e-18i)?  If you _did_ get significant imaginary components, then **edit your question** to show which bins you zeroed out -- preferably graphically, or with math, not with a bunch of code.