Pre-echo in digital sources
By digital filtering I have got pre-echo. Is this pre-echo in ADC or something very mystical happening.. https://youtu.be/b9XvUYTCYtc?si=2LuRteyo_ZoebDxu

you will need to explain what exactly you do when you say "digital filtering". It's very unlikely due to your ADC, and very likely due to the filtering you do. So: show us your filter! and: make sure it really does what it should. The way to test a digital filter at first isn't by sending some complex music through it, but by sending a pulse, and observing the impulse response. (or, equivalently, by sending a PN sequence, and correlating the output with the same; if the sequence is sufficiently white, that's also going to yield the impulse response.)

Hello. You know about masking the frequencies. First I go to logarithm of the signal. Then I delete all frequencies above some value. It is not like classical FIR filtering

well, it's what causing these audible effects. So, you'll have to describe it in great detail in your question! (not just superficially in a comment ;) ) Looking forward to reading about it! Note that "deleting all frequency above some value" sounds like a bad idea, see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins

There is a known effect when using the Parks-McClellan method to design digital filters with a wide passband, that they have pre-echo and post-echo.  It's because of the equally-spaced ripples in the passband.  That's like multiplying by a cosine function that that creates the pre- and post-echoes.

Here is my filtering: for(iter2=2; iter2<array_size/2; iter2++)
if(array[iter2]-array[iter2+1]>5e-3
&& array[iter2]-array[iter2-1]>5e-3) array[iter2]=0.0; Thank you all!

As I understand I delete all masking frequencies, and the unmasked output is signal-dependent echo

no,  this is probably not what is at fault (though it will lead to very bad audio artifacts, but different, additional ones). As I asked, describe your filtering 1. in your question and 2. in much detail. You're giving us a loop over arrays that you haven't defined. What you're actually doing here is left to us to guess. Can't work with that. Edit your question and include a detailed documentation of your full algorithm.

Sorry, what is unclear? The filtering is very simple, but I forgot that this is done to new array. for(iter2=2; iter2<array_size/2; iter2++) if(array[iter2]-array[iter2+1]>5e-3 && array[iter2]-array[iter2-1]>5e-3) new_array[iter2]=0.0;  The rest of the algorithm is used to calculate fft using fftw https://www.fftw.org/


Then I delete all frequencies above some value.

That is very likely time domain aliasing.
Time-variant frequency domain processing is mathematically quite difficult. Getting the framing right is tricky: you need to determine frame size, overlap, analysis window, synthesis window, etc. This choice depends a lot on how aggressive your spectral manipulation is and how quickly it changes, and how well you can control the phase of the equivalent filtering operation.

There are a lotta people that don't understand that the only convolution they're getting from the FFT is circular convolution. (And that Overlap-Add and Overlap-Save are means for using this circular convolution tool to perform linear convolution.) Deleting all frequencies above some value is like multiplying all those frequency components by zero. Multiplying in the frequency domain is convolving in the time domain, but with the DFT it's circular convolution. So, whatever you multiply in the frequency domain needs to be the DFT of an FIR that's short enough for OLA or OLS to work with it.

If the time-variant frequency-domain filtering is constant for a frame (i.e. the frequency response changes incrementally only when the frame changes), you can get away with that for Overlap-Add and the overlapping and adding will be the portamento or cross-fading or transition from the FIR filter of one frame to a slightly different FIR filter of the next frame.  It's not great, it's like linear cross-fading.  But with Overlap-Save you will get a click (a jump discontinuity) if the FIR changes between adjacent frames. In any case, the FIR needs to be windowed to the same length.

As I understand I delete all masking frequencies, and the unmasked output is signal-dependent echo. Thank you all!
